# Bulma styling of required attribute for input nested in label

Tags: html, css, bulma

Using the code [recommended by Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/file/) to define a file selection input form, styles for the `required` attribute will not be applied.

The form looks like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <div class="field is-vertical">
    <label class="label">Working file</label>
    <div id="id_file_to_work_on" class="file has-name is-fullwidth">
      <label class="file-label">
        <input type="file" name="file_to_work_on" class="file-input" required>
        <span class="file-cta">
          <span class="file-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="file-label">
            Please select…
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="file-name">
          Nothing selected, yet.
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <button type="submit" class="button is-primary" name="start_work">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The CSS for the required attribute like this:

```css
:required {
  background: red;
}
```

A respective [JSFiddle exists](https://jsfiddle.net/am8zuc2t/).

**Edit**: `required` should not be a css class for the label but just an attribute for the input field, as described by [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Looking at the Browser dev tools, the styling is applied to `input :required`, but isn't visible as the label styling hides it.

Is this an issue with Bulma or am I simply missing something obvious? A pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is all mine (of course) as the `novalidate` attribute of the form prevents the validation to be done. Removing this attribute results in the browser validation working just fine, including some styling that neatly fits into the Bulma look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

Labels don't support `required` attribute:

[Label attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

[Inherited global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

Instead, You can add css class `.required` to the label and change your css to:

`:required, .required {
  background: red;
}`

Example:

```css
:required,
.required {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <div class="field is-vertical">
    <label class="label required">Working file</label>
    <div id="id_file_to_work_on" class="file has-name is-fullwidth">
      <label class="file-label required">
        <input type="file" name="file_to_work_on" class="file-input" required>
        <span class="file-cta">
          <span class="file-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="file-label">
            Please select…
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="file-name">
          Nothing selected, yet.
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <button type="submit" class="button is-primary" name="start_work">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. 'required' not being an attribute for labels is a valid remark and I should have removed the temporary workaround of applying this. Only the 'required' attribute of the input element should be respected.